# how to check if user is logged-in in flask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am using the following code... but I don't know how to check if a user is signed in or not.

```py
@app.route('/signup', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form1 = Signup()
    if form1.validate_on_submit():
        signin = auth.create_user_with_email_and_password(form1.email_address.data, form1.password.data)
        user = auth.send_email_verification(signin['idToken'])  # for email verification

        database(name=form1.name.data, email_address=form1.email_address.data)

        return render_template('email_verification.html')
    if form1.errors != {}:   # if no errors occur from validators
        for err_msg in form1.errors.values():
            flash(err_msg, category='danger')
    return render_template('sign-up.html', form1=form1)


@app.route('/signin', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form2 = Signin()
    if form2.validate_on_submit():
        user = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(form2.email.data, form2.password.data)
        user = auth.refresh(user['refreshToken'])
        data = auth.get_account_info(user['idToken'])   # get user information
        email_verified = data['users'][0]['emailVerified']
        name = db.collection('users').document(form2.email.data).get()
        if name.exists:
            name_data = name.to_dict()['name']
        if email_verified:
            return redirect(url_for('account_page', user=name_data))
        else:
            return render_template('email_verification.html')

    if form2.errors != {}:   # if no errors occur from validators
        for err_msg in form2.errors.values():
            flash(err_msg, category='danger')
    return render_template('sign-in.html', form2=form2)


@app.route('/account')
def account_page():
    user = request.args.get('user')
    return render_template('account.html', user=user)
```

inside `/account` i want to give access only to those users who are signed in or else they shall be redirected to the `signup` page.

how can I achieve this?

Comment: look for `flask.session` in official documentation, you will surely get answers, there are several tutorials on it as well, its just you have to search for them

Comment: @YashasviBhatt yes, I have seen the documentation but, some people recommended `flask-login` and some recommended `session` and I don't know which one is better.

Comment: I am currently working on similar kind of project and I do find `flask.session` very easy

Comment: @YashasviBhatt alright! thanks